# How to populate two or more comboboxes from a single select query in C#

Tags: c#

I want to populate my two comboboxes from a single query like only the first combobox is being populated.

Here is my code:

```
private void loadcourses()
{
    try
    {
        using (sqlcon)
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
            coursecmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM DegCourses", sqlcon);                 
            reader = coursecmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while(reader.Read())
                cmbcoursecode.Items.Add(reader.GetString(1));
                cmbcoursedesc.Items.Add(reader.GetString(2));
            }
            reader.Close();
        }                
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

When I execute this code, it only populates the first combobox, `cmbcoursecode` -- the other does not populate.

Can you help me please?

Comment: add `{}` to `while`: `while(reader.Read()) { ... }` instead of `while(reader.Read())` which loop one operation only

Comment: You've missed Curly { } bracket Scope of your while remained only for next statement i.e `cmbcoursecode.Items.Add(reader.GetString(1));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify curly braces to your while loop, in that case the scope of the while will be just the next statement. Change your while like following

```
while(reader.Read()) 
{
   cmbcoursecode.Items.Add(reader.GetString(1));
   cmbcoursedesc.Items.Add(reader.GetString(2));
}
```